# How to add custom view and actions to django admin panel?

Tags: python, django

I'm new at Python and Django development. I'm trying to make a simple blog.

Right now what i am trying to do is create a admin function to show comments that not approved by admin yet. I like to show that comments and offer accept or reject choices to admin.

The problem is, i don't know the steps. I made some searches online but couldn't find what we are looking for. What are the steps to do this? What i need to learn to do this?

How do i add add custom list, buttons and functionality? I don't event know where to write code for my custom admin functionality.

Ps: I'm not looking for someone to write code for me. I'm just looking for guidelines.

Comment: The best guideline you can be given is to follow the [Django Tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/).  It covers all of the functionality you are trying to find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using django-admin-plus (https://github.com/jsocol/django-adminplus) which does exactly what you want:

> AdminPlus aims to be the smallest possible extension to the excellent Django admin component that lets you add admin views that are not tied to models.
>
> All AdminPlus does is allow you to add simple custom views (well, they can be as complex as you like!) without mucking about with hijacking URLs, and providing links to them right in the admin index.